# What is the derivation for "Partial Expectation"?

Tags: distributions, conditional-expectation, lognormal-distribution, partial-moments

On the Wikipedia page for [Log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

It is written that

$$E[X|X>k]Pr(X>k)=\int_{k}^{\infty}xf_{X}(x)dx$$

I know it is probably simple, but I am still wondering the derivation. Since I know that

$$E[X|Y=y]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$$

But I don't know why the first integral is always true.

Comment: Closely [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576786/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to  think about the conditional density.  The density of $X|X>k$ is zero when $X\leq k$, so it's proportional to $f_X(x)I(X>k)$. The constant of proportionality is given by the fact that a density has to integrate to 1, so the conditional density is
$$g_X(x)=\frac{f_X(x)I(X>k)}{P(X>k)}$$
So,
$$E[X|X>k]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\frac{f_X(x)I(X>k)}{P(X>k)}\,dx=\int_k^\infty x\frac{f_X(x)}{P(X>k)}\,dx$$
where the last step is based on noticing that the integral up to $k$ has to be zero.
This then rearranges to give what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Just to be sure, When you write$g_{X}(x)=\frac{f_{X}(x)I(X \gt k)}{P(X>k)}$ is this using the same logic/formula as $f_{X|Y}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$, with  Y being the condition $X>k$ and hence $f_{Y}$ being represented by $Pr(X>K)$ and the joint density just multiplying by the indicator?

Answer (score 0):

The first equation can be derived using two fundamental formulas:

- The formula for the expectation of a random variable $X$ given event $A$:
  $$E(X\mid A)=\frac{E(XI(A))}{P(A)}\tag1$$
- The formula for the expectation of a function $h$ of a random variable $X$ (often described as [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/398918/145128)): If $X$ has density $f_X$, then
  $$ E [h(X)] = \int h(x) f_X(x)\, dx.\tag2$$

In your situation, apply formula (1) with $A:=\{X>k\}$, obtaining
$$E(X\mid X>k)=\frac{E [XI(X>k)]}{P(X>k)}.$$ Now apply (2), noting that $XI(X>k)$ can be written $h(X)$, where $h$ has the form
$$
h(x):=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if $x>k$}\\
0&\text{if $x\le k$}
\end{cases}.
$$ This gives
$$ E [XI(X>k)]=\int_k^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx.$$